# Websphere SSO Login Exception

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on

I have configured Websphere for SSO with LDAP security.

It was configured correctly, and was working fine. I have corrupted something and not able to recover.

System is throwing following **error**, can you please help me what error I may have made?

> SECJ0336E: Authentication failed for user webuser2 because of the
>   following exception
>   com.ibm.ws.security.registry.unix.UnixRegistryException
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.unix.UnixRegistryImpl.checkPassword(UnixRegistryImpl.java:139)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.checkPassword(UserRegistryImpl.java:339)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.ltpa.LTPAServerObject.authenticate(LTPAServerObject.java:980)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.ltpaLoginModule.login(ltpaLoginModule.java:655)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have somehow switched to the Local OS registry (based on the `com.ibm.ws.security.registry.unix.UnixRegistryException` exception).

The easiest probably will be to disable security and reenable it once again, this time selecting LDAP.

To disable security you have to stop (or kill WAS if you cant stop it) and either:

- use `wsadmin -conntype NONE` command. At the `wsadmin` prompt, type `securityoff`
- or edit manually `security.xml` and change in the first line `enabled` from `true` to `false`, like this:  `enabled="false"`

  Then start server and configure your security correctly via console. Save and restart again.